# Copy command crash pod startup on Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, command, kubernetes-pod

I'm new with Kubernetes and I'm trying to understand about the commands.
Basically what I'm trying to do is to create a Tomcat deployment, add an nfs and after that I copy the war file to the tomcat webapps.
But its failing

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: webapp11-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: webapp11
    spec:
      volumes:
        - name: www-persistent-storage
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: claim-webapp11
      containers:
      - name: webapp11-pod
        image: tomcat:8.0
        volumeMounts:
          - name: www-persistent-storage
            mountPath: /apps/build
        command: ["sh","-c","cp /apps/build/v1/sample.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps"]
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
```

As far as I understand when the image when an image has a command, like catalina.sh run on the Tomcat image, it will have a conflict with a command from the kubernetes.
Is that correct?
There is anyway to run a command after the pod starts?
thanks

Comment: You can mount directly your file to `/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/sample.war`, in this case your volume should be of type `File`. When you issue a new command, the `catalina.sh run` will not execute so the container will not stay alive. If you have multiple war files, you can mount the whole folder directly to `/usr/local/tomcat/webapps`

Comment: I don't want to do that, because I will have to create a new pv for every new version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, what you want is probably something like this:

```
command: ["sh","-c","cp /apps/build/v1/sample.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps && exec /whatever/catalina.sh"]
```

Or you could move the `cp` into an `initContainer` so you don't have to override the default command for your Tomcat container.